# Custom KMDF driver installed but not in driver list

Tags: kmdf

I'm attempting to build/install a "custom" KMDF driver (really it’s just the KMDF template in Visual Studio as is). My goal is to take a [PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) device in the device manager and update its driver to my new custom driver.

I build the KMDF template, generate an *.inf, right click and install, and I get a message saying that the operation completed.

I then go to [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), right click my PCIe card, *Update Driver*, *Browse for Drivers*, *Let me pick from a list*, show all devices, and at this point I would expect to see "Your Manufacturer Name" in the list, but I don't. I tried changing the "ManufacturerName" in my *.inf file in Visual Studio to a unique name, but I still don't see it in the list.

Also, I'm not seeing any relevant driver information with "driverquery /V"

What do I need to do to make my custom driver appear in the list such that I can "assign" it to the hardware device?

Comment: What programming language? C++? C#? Since it is Windows only, tag related to that may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was that I had my configuration build set to x86 instead of x64, and I'm on an x64 machine. I changed it, and now it's working.